# Updating Auto Suggestions on Space Key Press In Vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3

Hie i am Implementing Auto suggestion on search input
it has 2 feature where it suggests the next word as well as the approxiamte sentence/Question.
i have implemented most of the things..
i am stuck in the second half implementation where the questions which i am displaying in the dropdown will have to be updated when user press the Space key..

```
<template>
    <div>
    <div class="RNNXgb">
      <div class="SDkEP">
        <div class="iblpc" v-if="isOpen">
          <div class="CcAdNb">
            <span class="QCzoEc z1asCe MZy1Rb">
              <i class="ti-search" />
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="a4bIc">
          <div class="pR49Ae gsfi"></div>
          <input
            class="gLFyf gsfi"
            maxlength="2048"
            type="text"
            aria-autocomplete="both"
            aria-haspopup="false"
            autocapitalize="off"
            autocomplete="off"
            autocorrect="off"
            role="combobox"
            spellcheck="false"
            aria-label="Search"
            @input="onChange"
            v-model="search"
            @keydown.down="onArrowDown"
            @keydown.up="onArrowUp"
            @keydown.enter="onEnter"
            @keyup.space="getData"
            placeholder="Search your Query"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="dRYYxd">
          <div class="BKRPef" v-if="isOpen" aria-label="Clear" role="button">
            <span
              class="ExCKkf z1asCe rzyADb"
              role="button"
              tabindex="0"
              @click="closeDropdown"
            >
              <i class="ti-close"></i
            ></span>
            <span class="ACRAdd"></span>
          </div>
          <div
            class="XDyW0e"
            aria-label="Search by voice"
            role="button"
            tabindex="0"
          >
            <i class="ti-microphone"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="Tg7LZd" type="submit" aria-label="Search Your Query">
        <div class="zgAlFc">
          <span class="z1asCe MZy1Rb">
            <i class="ti-search icon" />
          </span>
        </div>
      </button>
      <div class="UUbT9" style="margin-top:40px">
        <div class="aajZCb">
          <!-- <div class="xtSCL"></div> -->
          <div style="height:150px;overflow-y:scroll" v-if="isOpen">
            <ul id="autocomplete-results" class="G43f7e">
              <li
                v-for="(result, i) in articles"
                :key="i"
                @click="setResult(result)"
                class="sbct"
                :class="{ 'is-active': i === arrowCounter }"
              >
                <div class="eIPGRd">
                  <div class="sbic sb43">
                    <i class="ti-search" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="pcTkSc">
                    <span class="wM6W7d WggQGd">{{ result }}</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div
            v-show="isOpen"
            style="height:150px;overflow-y:scroll;border-top: 1px solid #e8eaed;"
          >
            <ul id="autocomplete-results" class="G43f7e">
              <li
                v-for="(result, i) in results"
                :key="i"
                @click="setResult(result)"
                class="sbct"
                :class="{ 'is-active': i === arrowCounter }"
              >
                <div class="eIPGRd">
                  <div class="sbic sb43">
                    <i class="ti-search" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="pcTkSc">
                    <span class="wM6W7d WggQGd">{{ result }}</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "SearchAutocomplete",
  props: {
    //   items: {
    //     type: Array,
    //     required: false,
    //     default: () => [],
    //   },
    isAsync: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: false,
      default: false,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      articles: [
        "the",
        "be",
        "to",
        "of",
        "and",
        "a",
        "in",
        "that",
        "have",
        "I",
        "it",
        "for",
        "not",
        "on",
        "with",
        "he",
        "as",
        "you",
        "do",
        "at",
        "this",
        "but",
        "his",
        "by",
        "from",
        "they",
        "we",
        "say",
        "her",
        "she",
        "or",
        "an",
        "will",
        "my",
        "one",
        "all",
        "would",
        "there",
        "their",
        "what",
        "so",
        "up",
        "out",
        "if",
        "about",
        "who",
        "get",
        "which",
        "go",
        "me",
        "when",
        "make",
        "can",
        "like",
        "time",
        "no",
        "just",
        "him",
        "know",
        "take",
        "people",
        "into",
        "year",
        "your",
        "good",
        "some",
        "could",
        "them",
        "see",
        "other",
        "than",
        "then",
        "now",
        "look",
        "only",
        "come",
        "its",
        "over",
        "think",
        "also",
        "back",
        "after",
        "use",
        "two",
        "how",
        "our",
        "work",
        "first",
        "well",
        "way",
        "even",
        "new",
        "want",
        "because",
        "any",
        "these",
        "give",
        "day",
        "most",
        "us",
      ],
      items: [
        "Apple is a fruit",
        "Banana",
        "Orange",
        "Mango not includd",
        "Pear",
        "Peach not",
        "Grape",
        "Tangerine not",
        "Pineapple",
      ],
      isOpen: false,
      results: [],
      search: "",
      isLoading: false,
      arrowCounter: -1,
    };
  },
  watch: {
    items(value, oldValue) {
      if (value.length !== oldValue.length) {
        this.results = value;
        this.isLoading = false;
      }
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    document.addEventListener("click", this.handleClickOutside);
  },
  destroyed() {
    document.removeEventListener("click", this.handleClickOutside);
  },
  methods: {
    setResult(result) {
      this.search = result;
      this.isOpen = false;
      alert(result);
    },
    filterResults() {
      this.results = this.items.filter((item) => {
        return item.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.search.toLowerCase()) > -1;
      });
    },
    onChange() {
      this.$emit("input", this.search);
      this.filterResults();
      this.isOpen = true;
    },
    handleClickOutside(event) {
      if (!this.$el.contains(event.target)) {
        this.isOpen = false;
        this.arrowCounter = -1;
      }
    },
    closeDropdown() {
      this.search = "";
      this.isOpen = false;
    },
    onArrowDown() {
      if (this.arrowCounter < this.results.length) {
        this.arrowCounter = this.arrowCounter + 1;
      }
    },
    onArrowUp() {
      if (this.arrowCounter > 0) {
        this.arrowCounter = this.arrowCounter - 1;
      }
    },
    onEnter() {
      this.search = this.results[this.arrowCounter];
      this.isOpen = false;
      this.arrowCounter = -1;
      alert(this.search);
    },
    onSearch() {
      alert(this.search);
    },
    getData(){
      alert("space pressed")
    }
  },
};
</script>

<style>
.sb43 {
  background-size: 20px;
  min-height: 20px;
  min-width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}

.sbic {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 14px;
}

.WggQGd {
  color: #52188c;
}

.wM6W7d {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #212121;
  flex: auto;
  align-items: center;
  word-break: break-word;
  padding-right: 8px;
}
.pcTkSc {
  display: flex;
  flex: auto;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 0;
  max-height: none;
  padding: 6px 0;
}
.eIPGRd {
  flex: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 20px 0 14px;
}
.sbct {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  min-width: 0;
  max-height: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.sbct:hover {
  background: #eee;
}
.G43f7e {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.xtSCL {
  border-top: 1px solid #e8eaed;
  margin: 0 14px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
}
.aajZCb {
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 9px 8px -3px rgb(64 60 67 / 24%),
    8px 0 8px -7px rgb(64 60 67 / 24%), -8px 0 8px -7px rgb(64 60 67 / 24%);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 24px 24px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.UUbT9 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 690px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: -1px;
  z-index: 989;
  cursor: default;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}
.gLFyf {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  word-wrap: break-word;
  outline: none;
  display: flex;
  flex: 100%;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  margin-top: -37px;
  height: 34px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.gLFyf {
  height: 39px !important;
  line-height: 39px;
  margin-top: -42px;
}
.gLFyf.i4ySpb {
  display: block;
}
.gsfi,
.lst {
  font: 16px arial, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  line-height: 34px;
  height: 34 px !important;
}
.pR49Ae {
  color: transparent;
  flex: 100%;
  white-space: pre;
  height: 39px !important;
  line-height: 39px;
}
.a4bIc {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.XDyW0e {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  cursor: pointer;
  align-items: center;
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0 8px;
  width: 24px;
  line-height: 44px;
}
.ACRAdd {
  border-left: 1px solid #dfe1e5;
  height: 65%;
}
.ExCKkf {
  margin-right: 12px;
}
.ExCKkf {
  height: 100%;
  color: #70757a;
  vertical-align: middle;
  outline: none;
}
.BKRPef {
  padding-right: 4px;
}
.BKRPef {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  cursor: pointer;
  align-items: center;
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0 8px;
  line-height: 44px;
}
.dRYYxd {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin-top: -5px;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.QCzoEc {
  color: #9aa0a6;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}
.CcAdNb {
  margin: auto;
}
.iblpc {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-right: 6px;
  margin-top: -7px;
}
.RNNXgb {
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 1px rgb(64 60 67 / 16%);
  height: 39px;
  width: 690px;
  border-radius: 24px;
  z-index: 3;
  height: 44px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.SDkEP {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px 4px 0 16px;
  padding-left: 14px;
}
.Tg7LZd {
  height: 44px;
  width: 44px;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  padding-right: 13px;
}
.zgAlFc {
  background: none;
  color: #4285f4;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  margin: auto;
}
.z1asCe {
  display: inline-block;
  fill: currentColor;
  height: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
  position: relative;
  width: 24px;
}
.z1asCe i {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  background: silver;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  margin-top: 24px;
}
:hover::-webkit-scrollbar {
  background: silver;
  /* color:pink; */
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 0.002px;
}
</style>
```

this is just a dummy/demo version it has different implementation but the logic and flow remains same. can anyone of you help me in this

Comment: i got the solution to this..
i just called a function on space key pressed and replaced the whole list which is working fine for me