# updating the list and re-render the vue-template

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs3

i have a scenario where on certain point the dropdown list of values are to be updated.like suppose we have a list of fruits in dropdown. on key-press i will update the the list of fruits with list of flowers this is just example.
how can i update the list live?
i read the reactivity in depth [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html)
but i didnt get much help from it..
this question is the part of this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69707725/updating-auto-suggestions-on-space-key-press-in-vuejs)

Answer (score 0):

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  
  data: () => ({
type: 'fruits',
fruits: ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry'],
animals: ['cat', 'dog', 'rabbit'],
  }),
  
  computed: {
list() {
  return {
    fruits: this.fruits,
    animals: this.animals
  }[this.type]
}
  },
  
  methods: {
change(type){
  this.type = type
}
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click.prevent="change('animals')">
    Animals
  </button>
  <button @click.prevent="change('fruits')">
    Fruits
  </button>
  
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in list">{{ item }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Added a simple snippet to show how can be reactivity used to display list based on some option.

Comment: no i think you got me wrong, i wont be having the second list i will get it from backend on top of that the first lis itself should get replaced by the second list which is coming from data-base

Comment: anyways i found the solution to my question i just resigned the values to list